# android - add images from drawable folder into a created file directory

Tags: android, file, directory, android-file

I'm looking to be able to take png images (called 1.png, 2.png, 3.png) that I have stored in my apps drawable folder and copy/save them to a file directory that is created by my app on launch.
I've tried `.createnewfile()` but was unable to get anything to work.
code for creating my file directory below:

```
//-----create file directory for images
public void createDirectory() {

    try {

        File imageDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/C2AT_IMAGES");

        if (!imageDirectory.exists()) {

            imageDirectory.mkdirs();

            //something here to take images from drawable folder and place them into my newely created directory

            File imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/C2AT_IMAGES", //something here getDrawable maybe?
                    );
            imageFile.createNewFile();


        }

    }

    catch (Exception e) {

        Log.d("MAKE_DIR", "error creating directory");

    }

}
```

thanks

Comment: Please show the code you have tried, and what errors you are getting

Comment: Are these drawables being used in the app or are you interested in just getting bitmap's onto the external directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, this is how I done it:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.maptile_1);

                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);

                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/C2AT_IMAGES"
                        + File.separator + "test.jpg");
                try {
                    f.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    toastMsg = e.toString();
                    toast();
                }
```